# Using stop in action script 3.0 for two objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an instance of Gear and one of bLine. When the Gear gets on the bLine, they both start moving simultaneously. I am trying to stop both of them at one frame, I don't want the objects to go off the stage. Since my gear's move was created through a motion tween and my bLine moves through a function, I am not sure how that can be accomplished.

Code inside of the Gear instance:

```
var ev2:Event = new Event("transfer");

dispatchEvent(ev2);
```

Code inside of bLine:

```
import flash.events.Event;

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Move);

function Move(e:Event):void {
this.x=this.x+3;

};
```

Main timeline:

```
gear.addEventListener("transfer",transferGear);

function transferGear(e:Event) {
bLine.gotoAndPlay(2);

};
```

I don't know if there is a way how I could stop the bLine inside of the Gear instance, in order to be able to stop both objects at the same time.

Comment: Don't you want to use `gotoAndStop(2)` instead? Not sure if i understated you.

Comment: No, that's what I have as of right now for the dispatcher and make both objects move for a little. After a while, I would like to make them stop, both at the same time. So I don't know how would I make both of them stop.

Comment: oh, I think i get it. You want to remove frame event listener?

Comment: No..after the objects move, eventually I will either have to enter a key frame in bLine and add a event dispatcher but I don't know when, since I have to synchronize it and make it stop at the same time with the gear.

Comment: But you want to stop both animations? If you remove frame listener the animation stops. Can you paste `bLine.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bLine.Move);` inside `transferGear` function? UPDATED

Comment: i meant bLine.Move

Comment: It looks like it completely stops the bLine. But yes, I want to stop both animations after they move a couple of seconds

Comment: ok then I don't get it. You want them both to stop by it's bad that bLine stops? hym... Where your `dispatchEvent(ev2);` maybe you want to move this code to last frame and than call `stop()`?

Comment: I want to stop it AFTER they move both for a couple of frames! Not before they move.

Comment: Can you show us the .fla CS6 or older? You need to be more specific are all this code located at fist frame in each object?